# Sentinel-2 Level 2A Product Archive in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

My study target region is Eastern Africa (from 2017) and am interested in Sentinel-2 level 2A products from Google Earth Engine (GEE). However, the earliest imagery I could find in GEE for this region is from December 2018. But for France (my comparative study area), the archive dates back to March 2017.

How can I access the Sentinel-2 Level 2A products in Google Earth Engine before December 2018 for this target region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good practice to provide an example how how you tried to access the S2-A data in Earth Engine, perhaps something went wrong.

Most likely there is no data available for your time period because S2 started covering the region later. Another suggestion is to check the S2 level 1C collection, this is often the most complete set available:

```
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2016-04-01','2019-05-31')
print(sentinel.limit(10))

var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2016-04-01','2019-05-31')

print(sentinel.limit(10))
```

Comment: Thanks @Jobbo90 and JepsonNomad, S2 has no archive for my study region before the dates.